# Starcraft 2: Issuing orders to custom game AI

Tags: starcraft-2

Is there a way to issue orders to allied AI players in custom games of Starcraft 2...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to issue orders to a stock AI, but you can customize the AI on a particular map to respond to certain behaviors, i.e. if I move my SCV to location X, start attacking the player in the North East start position. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yeah. that sort of thing. so that if move my forces in to attack (or something), the ai will respond in kind.

Comment: That's done in the map editor?

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible and i do not know if it will be in the future. This is one of the things that makes the achievements with AI allies harder than they should be. The only way to actually coordinate your attacks with the AI is to wait for their attack and help them or attack somewhere else and use them as distraction.